# Account Storage for non-Contract Accounts

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, storage

Is it possible to modify the account storage trie for non-contract accounts?  For example, if I want to prove that I have control of an account without having to send any ETH, could I generate a transaction that would put a given value in a given key of my account storage trie?  If so, how would you do this in the Geth console and show that it's done afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, as storage is only modified by the `SSTORE` opcode.

However, you can prove ownership of an account by signing a message using the private keys of that account. You can do this in geth using the `eth.sign` method. Web3js probably has `web3.eth.sign`.